# Transforming from json to xml in mule dataweave is not working

Tags: xml

If I send following JSON it works

```
{
  "abc":{
    "ccc":"ddd",
    "eee":"fff",
    "ggg":"aaa"
  }
}
```

it gives response like following that is what I want

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<abc>
<ccc>ddd</ccc>
<eee>fff</eee>
<ggg>aaaa</ggg>
</abc>
```

but if I pass following JSON

```
{
  "abc":{
    "ccc":"ddd",
    "eee":"fff",
    "ggg":[{"aaa":"a","bbb":"b"}]
   }
}
```

It gives following error

```
 ERROR 2016-04-23 21:15:57,407 [[datawave-demo].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
    ********************************************************************************
    Message: Exception while executing: 
        "ggg":["aaaa","bbb"]
        ^
    Cannot coerce a :array to a :object
    Type                : com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException
    Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
    ********************************************************************************
     Exception stack is:
     1. Cannot coerce a :array to a :object  (com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.coercion.exception.UnsupportedTypeCoercionException)
  com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.coercion.ObjectTypeCoercionValue:31 (null)
2. Exception while executing: 
        "ggg":["aaaa","bbb"]
        ^
Cannot coerce a :array to a :object (com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException)
  com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler:166 (null)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.coercion.exception.UnsupportedTypeCoercionException: Cannot coerce a :array to a :object
    at com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.coercion.ObjectTypeCoercionValue.evaluate(ObjectTypeCoercionValue.scala:31)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.coercion.ObjectTypeCoercionValue.evaluate(ObjectTypeCoercionValue.scala:13)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.writer.xml.XmlWriter.writeObject(XmlWriter.scala:109)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.writer.xml.XmlWriter.writeValue(XmlWriter.scala:98)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.Value$class.write(Value.scala:31)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.coercion.ObjectTypeCoercionValue.write(ObjectTypeCoercionValue.scala:13)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.writer.xml.XmlWriter.writeValue(XmlWriter.scala:95)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.Value$class.write(Value.scala:31)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonArray.write(JsonArray.scala:9)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.writer.xml.XmlWriter$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(XmlWriter.scala:151)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.writer.xml.XmlWriter$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(XmlWriter.scala:119)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:750)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonObjectSeq.foreach(JsonObjectSeq.scala:11)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.writer.xml.XmlWriter.writeObject(XmlWriter.scala:118)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.writer.xml.XmlWriter.writeValue(XmlWriter.scala:98)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.Value$class.write(Value.scala:31)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonObject.write(JsonObject.scala:10)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.writer.xml.XmlWriter$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(XmlWriter.scala:151)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.writer.xml.XmlWriter$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(XmlWriter.scala:119)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:750)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonObjectSeq.foreach(JsonObjectSeq.scala:11)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.writer.xml.XmlWriter.writeObject(XmlWriter.scala:118)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.writer.xml.XmlWriter.writeValue(XmlWriter.scala:98)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.Value$class.write(Value.scala:31)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonObject.write(JsonObject.scala:10)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.wrappers.DelegateValue$class.write(DelegateValue.scala:29)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.variables.VariableReferenceNode.write(VariableReferenceNode.scala:9)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.Engine.internalExecute(Engine.scala:98)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.Engine.execute(Engine.scala:67)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.Engine.execute(Engine.scala:203)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler.write(WeaveMessageProcessor.scala:163)
    at org.mule.transformer.simple.ObjectToByteArray.doTransform(ObjectToByteArray.java:63)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:415)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:425)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:373)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayloadAsBytes(DefaultMuleMessage.java:719)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpResponseBuilder.build(HttpResponseBuilder.java:190)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.sendResponseToClient(HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.java:97)
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:77)
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:34)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:65)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:69)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:185)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:1)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:114)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.MuleMessageProcessingManager.processMessage(MuleMessageProcessingManager.java:32)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListener$1.handleRequest(DefaultHttpListener.java:127)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.gri...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky because you want to convert all the objects to xml, and might be dealing with large objects that you do not want to explicitly add to the dataweave.  To get around this I did the following;

```
%dw 2.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
{
    abc: {
        (payload.abc - payload.abc.ggg),
        (payload.abc.ggg map ggg: $)
    }
}
```

I actually tell it to map all properties in the object, and exclude array items.  The I tell it to take the array item and use the "map" function to output all the elements.  It might not be in perfect order, but it cuts down the dataweave to minimal lines.

The output for this dataweave is;

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<abc>
  <ccc>ddd</ccc>
  <eee>fff</eee>
  <ggg>
    <aaa>a</aaa>
    <bbb>b</bbb>
  </ggg>
</abc>
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML for element `"ggg"` is expecting an `object`, not an `array`. Removing the square brackets `[]` from `[{"aaa":"a","bbb":"b"}]` should solve the issue and the resulting XML should look like the following:

```
<abc>
  <ccc>ddd</ccc>
  <eee>fff</eee>
  <ggg>
    <aaa>a</aaa>
    <bbb>b</bbb>
  </ggg>
</abc>
```